# Connecting from Apache NiFi to Confluent Cloud

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, confluent-cloud

We are trying to connect to Confluent Cloud from Apache NiFi using PublishKafka. Getting following error.
We are using PublishKafka with ssl setting and Kafka API key and secret to connect to connect to Kafka.

Unexpected error from pkckg.eastus.azure.confluent.cloud/20.23>java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: **the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty**

org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector [Consumer clientId=consumer-TestConnection-1, groupId=TestConnection] Unexpected error from pkc-56d1g.eastus.a>java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

2022-12-09 01:01:32,078 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient [Consumer clientId=consumer-TestConnection-1, groupId=TestConnection] Connection to node -1 (xxxx.eastus.azure.confluent.cloud/20.2>2022-12-09 01:01:32,078 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient [Consumer clientId=consumer-TestConnection-1, groupId=TestConnection] Bootstrap broker pkc-56d1g.eastus.azure.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: >2022-12-09 01:01:33,055 WARN [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-4] org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector [Producer clientId=producer-4] Unexpected error from pkc-56d1g.eastus.azure.confluent.cloud/20.237.15.111; closing connec>java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.(PKIXValidator.java:102)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:181)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:300)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:176)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:246)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:141)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:632)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1074)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1061)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1008)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.runDelegatedTasks(SslTransportLayer.java:430)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeUnwrap(SslTransportLayer.java:514)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:368)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshake(SslTransportLayer.java:291)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:173)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:547)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:485)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:547)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:325)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:240)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
at java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
at java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.(PKIXParameters.java:120)
at java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.(PKIXValidator.java:99)
... 25 common frames omitted
2022-12-09 01:01:33,055 WARN [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient [Producer clientId=producer-4] Connection to node -1 (xxxx.eastus.azure.confluent.cloud/x.x.x.x:9092) terminated>
2022-12-09 01:01:33,055 WARN [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient [Producer clientId=producer-4] Bootstrap broker pkc-56d1g.eastus.azure.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2022-12-09 01:01:33,087 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8] org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector [Consumer clientId=consumer-TestConnection-1, groupId=TestConnection] Unexpected error from pkc-56d1g.eastus.azure.confluent.cloud/20.>java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Comment: Question is lacking information about how you configured your Nifi client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below steps would resolve the connectivity issue:

1. From Confluent CLI Tools, generate API key and secret.
2. From Apache NiFi, Create new StandardRestrictedSSLContextService or StandardSSLContextService with the CA cert, path and password. If the cert is copied to default path, refer them in the Controller Services. Note: Default pwd would be changeit.
3. In the PublishKafkaRecord &  ConsumeKafkaRecord NiFi processor,

- a) use the above created SSL Context Service.
- b) Use the above generated API key and secret against the Username and Password properties in the Processors.
- c) Make sure the values for 'Security Protocol' and 'SASL Mechanism' properties in the NiFi processors match the configuration in Confluent Kafka.

This should be it for connecting Apache NiFi and Confluent Cloud